# getting error while debugging after knocoutjs update

Tags: html, knockout.js

I've updated the knockout js from 2.3.0 to 3.2.0.

When i start typing in text box, i'm getting following error

```
    0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: 
Unable to get property '$data' of undefined or null reference
```

my html:

```
<input data-bind="value: title, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enter: addTitle" id="Title" type="text" />

<input data-bind="click: addTitle" id="btn-add-title" type="button" value="Add" />
```

when i removed **enter: addTitle**, i'm not getting mentioned error. But the above html works fine in knockout 2.3.0

Helps much appreciated!

### Update

I'm getting error at the knockout 3.2.0 js file in following module

**bindingContext** looks undefined

```
    ko.bindingHandlers['event'] = {
    'init' : function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var eventsToHandle = valueAccessor() || {};
        ko.utils.objectForEach(eventsToHandle, function(eventName) {
            if (typeof eventName == "string") {
                ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, eventName, function (event) {
                    var handlerReturnValue;
                    var handlerFunction = valueAccessor()[eventName];
                    if (!handlerFunction)
                        return;

                    try {
                        // Take all the event args, and prefix with the viewmodel
                        var argsForHandler = ko.utils.makeArray(arguments);
                        viewModel = bindingContext['$data'];//**getting error message at this point**
                        argsForHandler.unshift(viewModel);
                        handlerReturnValue = handlerFunction.apply(viewModel, argsForHandler);
                    } finally {
                        if (handlerReturnValue !== true) { // Normally we want to prevent default action. Developer can override this be explicitly returning true.
                            if (event.preventDefault)
                                event.preventDefault();
                            else
                                event.returnValue = false;
                        }
                    }

                    var bubble = allBindings.get(eventName + 'Bubble') !== false;
                    if (!bubble) {
                        event.cancelBubble = true;
                        if (event.stopPropagation)
                            event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Update 2:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enter = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data) {
        //wrap the handler with a check for the enter key
        var wrappedHandler = function (data, event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                valueAccessor().call(this, data, event);
            }
        };
        //call the real event binding for 'keyup' with our wrapped handler
        ko.bindingHandlers.event.init(element, function () {
            return {
                keyup: wrappedHandler
            };
        }, allBindingsAccessor, data);
    }
};
```

Comment: If you are using `$data` inside your `addTitle()` function you have been doing it wrong all along anyway. Your HTML/binding code is fine. Show the implementation of that function instead.

Comment: Best add the entire implementation of the `enter` custom binding

Comment: I don't understand... This looks a bit like the official, built-in `event` binding handler. Did you modify that? Also, where is the binding handler for the `enter` binding?

Comment: @Tomalak I have added the module, it seems i have to update it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding handler's init function has this signature:

```
function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext)
```

but in your `enter` custom handler you call it as

```
ko.bindingHandlers.event.init(element, function () {}, allBindingsAccessor, data);
```

That's one argument short. Of course the `bindingContext` ends up undefined.

How about

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enter = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        //wrap the handler with a check for the enter key
        var wrappedHandler = function (viewModel, event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                valueAccessor().call(viewModel, event);
            }
        };
        var valueAccessor = function () {
            return {
                keyup: wrappedHandler
            };
        };
        //call the real event binding for 'keyup' with our wrapped handler
        ko.bindingHandlers.event.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
};
```

But really I would rather recommend using `ko.applyBindingsToNode` like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enter = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
            event: {
                keyup: function (event) {
                    var callback;
                    if (event.keyCode !== 13) return;
                    callback = valueAccessor();
                    if (typeof callback !== "function") return;
                    callback.call(viewModel);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please let me know the concept of using applyBindingsToNode, much interested to know.

Comment: Well, the name says it all. It applies bindings to a node. Its effect is the same as if you declare `data-bind="event: {keyup: handler}"` on the HTML element.